# Do higher versions of Android support lower versions of Android devices

Tags: android

What is the most useful version for developing an Android Application?

Comment: There is no such thing as Android 2.6

Answer (score 1):

Like Sean Owen said, there's no such thing as Android 2.6. Did you mean 2.3.6? The highest version before 3.x is currently 2.3.7.

Here's a great overview to see what android versions are most used today:
http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html

Then you can make up your mind on what platform version you will be targeting for your development.

Answer (score 0):

Android is only the OS so yes it can run on devices which have Android 2.1 installed. Newer versions of course require better hardware for some features. For example you could also install Windows 7 on a PC running Windows XP as long as your hardware requirements fit.

The most useful version? Well It would be kind of silly to release a new Android version without making it better don't you think? That's why you should always have your application up-to-date.

Since many users still have older versions installed on their device you should also support lower versions for your application. How far backward compatible you should go depends on your requirements for your application. If you only need features already supported by Android 2.1 make 2.1 your minimal required OS version.

Answer (score 0):

yes it will support... and It is and obvious case that higher version support lower version. real question is is lower version support application of higher version? and that also you can do using compatible library.